# How can I use perl debuggers pretty print for a hash in normal program code?

Tags: perl, debugging, pretty-print

In Perl debugger you can very nice output a hash like:

```
  DB<1> x \%my_hash
```

How can I use the debugger output method 'x' in my programm to log pretty formated hash data in my logfile?

Comment: Use `Data::Dumper` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper). It is a core module, so no installation required. It is a good debugging tool.

```
use Data::Dumper;

...

print Dumper \%my_hash;
```

Comment: Holy Bat Crapman!  TY!

Comment: @DanielSantos You're welcome. A bit unexpected after 8 years. :)